# Get data of affected rows after MySQL table update

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
connection.query("UPDATE table SET columnA = valA WHERE columnB = valB;",
    function(err, rows, fields) {
        
         ..some code..
    }
```

How can I get the data of the affected rows after this mysql query in NodeJS.

Like if it's a `SELECT` query, I can do something like

```
sql = rows[0];
id = sql.id;
```

I know there's a `rows.affectedRows` and `rows.changedRows` but it only gives the number of affected rows not the datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no property that holds this information after the statement is executed. You need to help yourself by extending a statement with logging such information.

```
SET @uids := '';
UPDATE table 
   SET columnA = valA 
 WHERE columnB = valB
   AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', @uids, id) );
SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM @uids);
```

In @uids you have the ids of updated rows.

Another approach is to do a select statement with your WHERE clause first (`WHERE columnB = valB`). So you get the rows for update. You can store ids and then run update only on given ids (`WHERE id IN ({yourIdSet})`).

Comment: Nice... Your answer works, but just for one column, in my case, I want to select multiple columns like `id`, `user`, `text` and `date`. So how can I get to do that?

Comment: It works regardless the amount of columns you need to select as you retrieve list of ids (primary keys). And by this list of ids you can then select any other columns you need (e.g. `select id, user, text, date from table where id in (@uids);`

Comment: Okay... Thanks man. I thought of that, but I  thought there might be a better way. Thanks I appreciate